# Using categorical variable as an index for other parameters in PyMC3

Tags: python, pymc3

I'm trying to use a categorical variable as an index to choose from a list of parameters for another distribution in PyMC3. I have tried doing this with both `pm.switch()` and by indexing an array of parameters. The code runs fine, but the categorical variable appears to be stuck at whatever I define as the testval.

Attempt 1:

```
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt

with pm.Model() as model:

    b = pm.Bernoulli('b', .2, testval=0)
    mu = pm.math.switch(b, 0, 10)
    n = pm.Normal('n', mu=mu, sd=1)

    trace = pm.sample(10000, tune=1000)
```

Attempt 2:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    b = pm.Bernoulli('b',.2, testval=1)
    mus = tt.as_tensor([0,10])
    n = pm.Normal('n', mu=mus[b], sd=1)

    trace = pm.sample(10000, tune=1000)
```

With both attempts, `pm.summary(trace)` shows that `b` is only being sampled as 0 in the first attempt and 1 in the second attempt (corresponding to the given testvals).

What am I doing wrong that the distribution of `b` is not being sampled as the distribution I defined?

Comment: This looks like something  that should work! What about if you estimate the standard  deviation? like `sd = pm.HalfNormal('sd', 10)`. Are you trying to run a GMM? Did you check this [example](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/notebooks/marginalized_gaussian_mixture_model.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pymc3 uses different step methods for `n` and `b` as one is discrete and the other one is continuous – it can't change them at the same time. At the start `b` is 1 and `n` is 10. If you propose to change `b` to 0 the logp will be way to small, as `n` would be 10 sd's from its mean. Changes to `n` will be accepted, but only if it doesn't move away from 10 too much. It will not get close enough to 0 that a change in `b` would get an reasonable probability.

The typical set of the posterior can be separated into two regions (something like {0} \times [-a, +a] and {1} \times [10-a, 10+a]) and the sampler can't move between them: Some discrete version of multi-modality.